# .NET Core BackgroundService equivalent in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-framework-version

Unnecessary trouble if the outer framework for each plugin eventually gets converted to .NET Core. However since the old legacy code dominates, it is required to down grade current plugin built using asp.net core back to asp.net.

One problem to solve is, one service currently written in .NET Core using `Extension.Hosting` inheriting from `BackgroundService`, and can be run simply adding as in `Startup.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

services.AddHostedService<SomeBackgroundService>();
```

I have been looking around without much success what could be minimal change can be done porting back to ASP.NET in this `SomeBackgroundService : BackgroundService`

Comment: There is no such thing on .NET Framework.

Comment: I think Scott Hanselmann wrote a good post about that [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390284/equivalent-of-ihostedservice-in-asp-net-framework-for-background-tasks)?